# Growing issues related to Multiple indexes on relational tables in schema

Tags: indexing, relational-database

I am working on “growing issues related to multiple indexes on relational tables in schema”, anyone can help me to find the research papers on this topic. I am in a remote area and haven‘t much resources to work on it please provide at least two papers.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). SO is not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service We try to fix your code, we do not write your code –

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming. I think you could post this question on http://cs.stackexchange.com.